# React Native Fetch Always return network error or 500 on Nox Emulator with laravel backend

Tags: laravel, react-native, xampp, fetch-api

I am in the process of upgrading my laravel application.
my old laravel using old version xampp.
Since new laravel 10 version require higher php version, I installed another newer xampp.

Everything works for both old and new laravel for website part using chrome.
I am using react native for mobile app using API part of laravel.
When I start laravel app with `php artisan serve --host 127.0.0.1 --port=8010`
My react native app fetching always return **network error**.
The api url is `http://127.0.0.1:8010/api/user`.

This only happen if I fetch from my react native app.
It works when I use same api on chrome, it return json. This works fine for both laravel on Chrome.
and It also works if I fetch same API to my old laravel.
My old laravel using same url without the port, since both xampp version using different port.

Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: Issue might be related to laravel cors. Have you tried resolving the cors policy issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn out the solution is I need to map my computer and emulator port

```
adb -s devicename reverse tcp:8010 tcp:8010
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using emulator then use 10.0.2.2 ip address. For real device check your local ip address for windows ipconfig. Also check http and https.